# Mule ESB HTTP inbound-endpoint path

Tags: http, path, relative-path, esb, mule

I am trying to get two mule projects to run at the same time that have similar paths, so that we can group our calls together (example http://domain.com/foo/service1 http://domain.com/foo/service2)

As a POC I have two projects, both that listen on localhost port 80.
project1 has a path of endpoint/v1
project2 has a path of endpoint/v2

Both deploy successfully to my mule server, but only project1's endpoint returns anything.

Any ideas on how to get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is only one socket actually listening on that port (80).
If you want to have more than one path, you need to group the endpoints together in the same application, and this application can act as a proxy and call the ones with the actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Seba's proposal, a common pattern is to have one app in charge of exposing an HTTP endpoint then to dispatch messages to JMS queues that are listened to by the apps in charge of processing specific paths (say /v1 in one app and /v2 in another app).

Comment: Yes, agree, that's what I actually meant by "and this application can act as a proxy and call the ones with the actual logic".

Comment: OK but it seems you suggest to have several HTTP endpoints in the proxy app while a single is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think in our use case it might make more sense to just have each end point listen to a different port.  We would want multiple developers working on our ESB layer where we will be performing transformations, so they would each work on their own projects.  Adding JMS queues/topics seems like overkill for this use case, as does having a parent router pass-through the requests to each service.